# Command to open a program that doesn't come with Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I know that I can use the command `firefox` to open Firefox but I would like to open Chromium.

How to archieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chromium's command is `chromium-browser`.

If you need to find the name of a command, you can right click your menu, click edit, and find the program's entry. Click edit on the entry and it will show you the command.

You can also begin typing the name of the program in a terminal (for example `chr`) and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to see a list of potential matches.